# How can I create a node CLI app that needs babel to run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to creaet a global node CLI app, but It depends on Babel to run.
I've added this to my package.json

```
"bin": {
    "kurly": "dist/index.js"
},
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "start": "yarn build && node dist/index.js"
},
```

and I'm installing it from my git using

```
npm install -g alexanderprod/kurly
```

But when installing it I get the following error

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/kurly/dist/index.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/kurly/dist/index.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

So it seems like npm didn't build it with babel before applying chmod.
And now I'm wonderging how to fix that, since I assume it makes no sense to upload dist/ to npm/git

Comment: *"since I assume it makes no sense to upload dist/ to npm/git"* Usually packages contain any compiled output. Babel is usually a dev dependency. You don't want your users to have to download all of Babel just to be able to use your package.

Comment: @FelixKling So i should upload the compiled dist directory?

Comment: Instead of the src, yes.